# Character Segmentation not working for all the characters

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, image-segmentation

For Indian License Plate Recognition, Character Segmentation does not segment all the characters from the license plate. For example, if the plate number is: MH20EE7601 and the segmented characters are H20EE7. and sometimes I don't get any numbers. How can I improve it?

image :

[image: Character Segmentation on license plate]

My Code is:
gray = cv2.cvtColor(box, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

```
gray = cv2.resize(gray, None, fx = 3, fy = 3, interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

rect_kern = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))

dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh, rect_kern, iterations = 1)
try:
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
except:
    ret_img, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
sorted_contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda ctr: cv2.boundingRect(ctr)[0])
```

I am new to python kindly help!

image 1:

[image: image1]

image 2:

[image: image2]

image 3:

[image: image 3]

Original images:

[image: original image1]

and original image 2:

[image: original image2]

Comment: first you could see all images which you create - gray, blur, etc - to see which step may need changes. And later you can try to use little different parameters to see if it can help.

Comment: can you provide the image link ?

Comment: @abhishek I have updated my post and shared the image as link with name image1

Comment: @shivani I mean the image on which we can work on. All of your image have some extra texts in it.

Comment: Why are you blurring your images. That makes it harder when the blur bleeds from one character to another. If you need to clean up noise, perhaps a median filter would be better. If the original images are a bit blurry, and the median does not help, then perhaps sharpen the images.

Comment: Sharp edges are the key.  But remember that character recognition is not perfect.  It's doing a statistical analysis, and sometimes there isn't enough information.

Comment: @Abhishek okay I have updated my post again and shared the images with name original image1 and 2